# ERC1155 Creating NFT

Tags: solidity, nft

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;


//import ERC1155 token contract from OpenZeppelin
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC1155/ERC1155.sol";
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract NFTXXX is ERC1155, Ownable {

    uint256 public constant Arcadiy = 0;
    uint256 public constant MAX = 1;

    constructor() ERC1155("http://ipfs.io/ipfs/{id}.json") {
        _mint(msg.sender, Arcadiy, 1, "");
        _mint(msg.sender, MAX, 2, "");
    }

    function mint(address account, uint256 id, uint256 amount) public onlyOwner {
        _mint(account, id, amount, "");
    }

    function burn(address account, uint256 id, uint256 amount) public {
        require(msg.sender == account);
        _burn(account, id, amount);

    }
}
```

[Images do not appear on OpenSea(testnet)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBlZp.png)

There are json files that i use for contract.

```
{
"image": "ipfs://bafybeienrrxym2d3b5u7glcvdrz63rztxkue7p4bly4fcsma55nupmxsvy", 
"description": "My first plant",
"name": "Cactus Arcadiy"
```

}

```
{
"image": "ipfs://bafybeieh4lcllyimopk6pmacjyx4atgdqsywvsia6nuuq6niucdqxwbq5i", 
"description": "GoodZone is a banya with pool",
"name": "Banya"
```

}

I think something is wrong with the referense for images ("http://ipfs.io/ipfs/{id}.json"), but i didn't find resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Your image uri from the metadata is working though.

It seems that you treat the `http://ipfs.io/ipfs/{id}.json` as your NFT's Metadata storage place (actually it is NOT), which might cause error like TOKEN_0 (Arcadiy) would try to retrieve your metadata in `http://ipfs.io/ipfs/0.json`.

Therefore, you should replace it with your own storage address, i.e., place your NFT Metadata to ipfs again and set the tokenURI to it.